# View resize is not working on first viewDidAppear call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Im changing frame of a `UIView` in side of `viewDidAppear`.

**Here is my `viewDidAppear` code**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
   CGRect newPosition =CGRectMake(44, 200, 697, 142);//hard code for testing purpose.
   myView.frame = newPosition;  //here i'm moving view to new position
}
```

On very first call of `viewDidAppear` `myView` remains on old position.
But on second call of `viewDidAppear` myView moves to `newPosition`;

**Why my view is not moving to newPosition on first call of `viewDidAppear`?**

Answer (score 0):

Hi you forgot `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {  
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];

       CGRect newPosition =CGRectMake(44, 200, 697, 142);//hard code for testing purpose.
       myView.frame = newPosition;  //here i'm moving view to new position
    }
```

But for changing of frame better to use :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGRect newPosition =CGRectMake(44, 200, 697, 142);//hard code for testing purpose.
    myView.frame = newPosition;  //here i'm moving view to new position
}
```

Also try to add small animation for frame changing it will be more cool.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect newPosition =CGRectMake(44, 200, 697, 142);//hard code for testing purpose.
        myView.frame = newPosition;  //here i'm moving view to new position
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
```

Final code will be :

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            CGRect newPosition =CGRectMake(44, 200, 697, 142);//hard code for testing purpose.
            myView.frame = newPosition;  //here i'm moving view to new position
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            }];
    }
```

Comment: no still same issue.i updated viewDidAppear with [super viewDidAppear:animated]; but still im same issue.one more thing my myView is outlet object.

Comment: Try now with small tip

Comment: that all i tried animation and all,it wasn't working with first call so i removed everything and just changed the frame of view with hardcoded value but still its not working.at the end i posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in `layoutSubviews`.

Example :

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

   CGRect newPosition =CGRectMake(44, 200, 697, 142);//hard code for testing purpose.
   myView.frame = newPosition;  //here i'm moving view to new position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account all the other answers I think the reason is that myView is nil when viewDidAppear is called at first and not nil when called subsequently:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
   [super viewDidAppear:animated]; // was missing

   CGRect newPosition = CGRectMake(44, 200, 697, 142);
   myView.frame = newPosition; // nil.frame = ...
}
```

And you should call super's implementation here, but that should not cause such a problem.

Another possible issue is that something causes `myView` to be repositioned after first `-viewDidAppear:`, so you position it, something repositions it again, you can debug this overriding `-setFrame:` for `myView` or using a symbol breakpoint somehow.

Comment: @walinaqvi so, you've checked it's not nil or you consider it not nil because it's "outlet object"?